# Accessibility not announcing formated currency properly

Tags: java, android, accessibility

I have a requirement in which I need to announce the formatted currency properly in accessibility.I have used Currency Formatter

NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
currencyFormatter.format(price)

It reads `$2.46 as 2 Dollars 46 cents` which is correct. but when price comes like `$0.44` it reads as `Dollar 0.44` but i need to announce  it as 44 cents.

Comment: Did you get the solution ?